# Maximum value of $f(x,y)=x^2+2y^2$ subject to constraint : $y-x^2+1=0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, qcqp

[image]

If $f(y)=2y^2+y+1,$

$f'(y)=4y+1=0\Rightarrow y=-\frac14,\; x=\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2$

$f''(y)=4>0,$ so I can't obtain a point of maxima.

What does this mean? Do I necessarily need to use Lagrange's Multiplier method for this?

Comment: Do you want to maximize or "minimize"?

Comment: @Math-fun maximise

Comment: @Math-fun I've attached the picture of the exact question that appeared in my exam

Comment: your approach to eliminate $x$ is fine: as a result you obtain a function that can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: @Math-fun so what does this mean? we can't obtain the maximum value? Answer given to me is 2

Comment: The answer given to you for the problem you posted is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remember:
$$x^2=y+1\ge 0 \Rightarrow y\ge -1.$$
So, it has the additional constraint on $y$. According to the [Extreme value theorem](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/calculus/calculus/applications-of-the-derivative/extreme-value-theorem), you must check the border and critical points:
$$\text{critical:} \ \ f(\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},-\frac14)=\frac78 \ \text{(local min)}\\
\text{border:} \ \ f(0,-1)=2 \ \text{(local max)}$$

Note: There is no global max, because for $x\to\infty$, $f(x,y)\to \infty$.

Comment: How did you get the border point?

Comment: $y=-1$ is the border point from the constaint $y\ge -1$, which has the pair $x^2=-1+1=0 \Rightarrow x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2=y+1$$

$$x^2+2y^2=y+1+2y^2=2\left(y+\dfrac14\right)^2+1-2\left(\dfrac14\right)^2\ge?$$

Comment: I don't understand this

Comment: @Abhay, Please pinpoint your query